# cut an int array column in a CSV without cutting another varchar array

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

I have a CSV where it looks like

```
details.csv

1,2,3,4,5,2015-07-30 23:17:12,2015-07-30 23:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.2,"{1,2,3}",{NORMAL},1,2,
2,2,6,4,5,2015-07-30 12:17:12,2015-07-30 12:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.8,"{4,5,6,7,8,9}",{BOOKING},1,2,
3,2,3,4,9,2015-07-30 10:17:12,2015-07-30 10:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.9,"{1,9}","{NORMAL,BOOKING}",1,2,
```

Here the 15 the column is empty and the 12 the column has no quotes when it is a single value(**{BOOKING}**) and have quotes when it has more than one value(**"{BOOKING,NORMAL}"**).

From this I wanted to remove the 11 the column which is a int array and not having fixed size.So the output will look like

```
mod_details.csv
1,2,3,4,5,2015-07-30 23:17:12,2015-07-30 23:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.2,{NORMAL},1,2,
2,2,6,4,5,2015-07-30 12:17:12,2015-07-30 12:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.8,{BOOKING},1,2,
3,2,3,4,9,2015-07-30 10:17:12,2015-07-30 10:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.9,"{NORMAL,BOOKING}",1,2,
```

So I tried:

```
sed 's/,"{.*}"//' details.csv > mod_details.csv
```

But the problem is I get the output as

```
mod_details.csv
1,2,3,4,5,2015-07-30 23:17:12,2015-07-30 23:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.2,{NORMAL},1,2,
2,2,6,4,5,2015-07-30 12:17:12,2015-07-30 12:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.8,{BOOKING},1,2,
3,2,3,4,9,2015-07-30 10:17:12,2015-07-30 10:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.9,1,2,
```

Where it also removes the 12 th column values which have more than one value because it too have quotes.Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's not particularly difficult. You only need to use a pattern more specific than `{.*}`:

```
sed 's/"{\([0-9],\)\+[0-9]}",//' details.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

As a step toward finding an answer, you might find the following shell function helpful.  I wrote it for viewing CSVs on the command line in a nice "pretty" layout.

Note it *deletes* the quoted commas and quoted newlines (and quoted double quotes), which may not be what you want, but which is useful for a quick viewing and having the columns line up correctly.

```
excel() {
    sed -E -e ':t' -e '/^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$/!{N;s/\n//;bt' -e'}' "$@" |
      awk -F\" -v OFS= 'NF>1 {for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/,/, "", $i)} 1' |
      sed 's/,/,"/g' | column -ts, | tr -d '"' | less -S
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvcut -C 11 details.csv
1,2,3,4,5,2015-07-30 23:17:12,2015-07-30 23:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.2,{NORMAL},1,2,
2,2,6,4,5,2015-07-30 12:17:12,2015-07-30 12:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.8,{BOOKING},1,2,
3,2,3,4,9,2015-07-30 10:17:12,2015-07-30 10:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.9,"{NORMAL,BOOKING}",1,2,
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting each line into array on `"` as delimiter is a much easier approach. Your int array then becomes element 1 of the array, which we can set to a null string, and the next one(element 2) will have extra comma appended to the end of it, so we can extract a sub-string of that starting from the second character. Now, we need to deal with returning double quotes to the `{NORMAL,BOOKING}` part somehow. With splitting line on `"` as delimiter, this is also taken care of, because then line will have field 3. In case of other lines, there's no more quotes, so our array of items will contain only items up to index 2. If there is index #3 we know that we must quote that.

The perl  one-liner below does exactly as described above:

```
$ perl -F'"' -lane '$F[1]="";$F[2]=substr($F[2],1);$F[3]= "\"" . $F[3] . "\"" if $F[3];print @F' inpu>
1,2,3,4,5,2015-07-30 23:17:12,2015-07-30 23:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.2,{NORMAL},1,2,
2,2,6,4,5,2015-07-30 12:17:12,2015-07-30 12:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.8,{BOOKING},1,2,
3,2,3,4,9,2015-07-30 10:17:12,2015-07-30 10:39:12,103.4,104.2,1.9,"{NORMAL,BOOKING}",1,2,
```